# How to get index of value in macro

Tags: indexing, global, stata, stata-macros

I have a global macro:

```
global global_macro sheep frog dragon
```

I loop over this macro and I want to be able to generate three new variables based on the current index value of `global_macro`:

```
foreach i in $global_macro {
    ***define local index***
          ...
    gen new_var_`index' = 5
}
```

So I want it to produce the variables `new_var_1`, `new_var_2`, and `new_var_3` because `sheep` is the first value in `global_macro`, `frog` is the second, and `dragon` is the third. `index` would first contain `1`, then `2`, and finally `3`.

I know that there is basically the opposite functionality in the extended macro function called `word`. This allows one to access a value in a macro based on the index - as opposed to accessing the index based on the value.

Is there a function to do what I would like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
clear
set more off

// original list/indices
local wordlist sheep frog dragon

// attach indices to words
quietly forvalues i = 1/3 {
    local creature : word `i' of `wordlist'
    local `creature'_idx `i'
}

// access indices based on words
foreach i in frog dragon sheep  {
    display "Creature `i' has index ``i'_idx'"
}
```

It can probably be refactored, but the main point is to create for each word a `local` that holds its corresponding index; then you can access any word's index (based on the word).

(I may be missing some obvious function/command to do what you want.)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
local n: word count $global_macro

forval index = 1/`n' {
    gen new_var_`index' = 5
}
```

Best